# How can I get facebook id\link for the instagram user

Tags: facebook, api, instagram

I use Instagram API to get user photos, but I also want to have access to facebook profile of this users over Facebook API.
How can I get facebook user id for current instagram user?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook and Instagram have not been integrated so there isn't a way to do this as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Instagram User ID. I'm not so sure about the facebook ID but...

Programmatically make a request to `https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1`
e.g. https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1

Without Code use the site:
https://www.thekeygram.com/find-instagram-user-id/